# Swift - Struct and Array

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I'm trying to modify an existing struct which is then used with an array. Is there a solution to the following?

```
struct pickerData {
    var key = ""
    var value = ""
}

var pickerArray = [pickerData]()
pickerArray.append(pickerData(key: "1", value: "2")) //OK up to know but
//I need to append a new key:value to this structure

pickerArray.append(pickerData(key: "1", value: "2",value2: "3")) // error
pickerArray.append(pickerData(key: "1", value: "2"),value2: "3") // error
```

I basically need a mutable struct, is this doable?

Comment: It's not clear what you're after, you want to extend `pickerData` with more properties?  This isn't possible – it could be that you want `pickerData.value` to be an `Array` or `Dictionary`

Comment: I'm trying to build an array with some key:value pairs where I don't yet know how many key:pair I will have nor will I know the key name. As an example I could start with an empty array  and dynamically add new key:pairs in a for loop. The Arry would start with () then  (key: "1"), then (key: "1", value: "2") then (key: "1", value: "2",value2: "3") and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of a `struct` cannot change; as your comment suggests that you want to add a *key:value* pair, you should be using a datatype that supports such pairs: a `Dictionary`.  (Technically, those aren't *key:value* pairs in a `struct`.)